# Image Inside of Artwork

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to place an image inside of another image of a magnifying glass using CSS.  I want to make sure the image will stay inside the circular lens part of the magnifying glass *no matter what*.  When I use absolute positioning it seems to move around whenever the webpage size changes, i.e. non-responsive.  How do I achieve this responsively  I am using bootstrap.

The type of magnifying glass I am working with looks like this:
[image]

The center is transparent now.  I also want to position the image so that the hand is fixed to the bottom of the page to give the effect of a complete image off the web page.  Here is some of my code below, the img-circle tag is a bootstrap class that is creating a circular image, other than that, I know absolute positioning is not on the right track as it depends on window size, here's the code snippet though since requested.

```css
img-circle {
  position : absolute;
  bottom   : 146px;
  border : black solid 4px;
}

.mag-glass {
  position : absolute;
  bottom   : 0;
  right    : 0;
  width    : 100%;
  height   : auto;
}
```

```html
      <div class = 'col-sm-4'>
        <img class = "mag-glass" src = "img/mag-glass.png">
        <img class = "img-circle" ng-src = "a dynamic map image goes here /{{lat}}/lng/{{lng}}">
      </div>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code? Or even better, create a snippet or bin?

Comment: Sure thing, just a moment

Answer (score 1):

You could try to edit the picture, set inside the glas a transparent layer and white outside. The picture inside the glass has to be a lower z-index than the picture with the glass. Remember, z-index only work if you have set a position (relative/absolute...)